# How do you open a detached database in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, mdf

I try to open the database YourGuruDB1 in this directory:

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data
```

I go to file and then open file.. Then it tells me, that i must ensure that the database is installed..

Previously I backed up and restored the database, and then detached it..I have no idea where the program dropped the database to..

But I want to open it with all its stored procedures like any other database that i have in SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you detached it, you need to attach it.

Just right click on the "Databases" node in SQL Server Managment Server, click "Attach", navigate to the data file you indicated, and tell it to attach the database.

Comment: But when i attach it back,,the database appears with no way to expand it to see the stored produres and tables.....it sits there like an mdf file... I cant execute any queries on it..SELECT * From YourGuruDB1.Users

Comment: Does it say "Offline" next to the database?

Comment: actually, I corrected it..I opened it copying the security files mdf, and log files...

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach back the database.